# Java getheight() and getWidth() of inner panel without set it to fix size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, layout-manager

I want to get height and width of inner panel.
I have set height and width to 100% by use of Miglayout.
while I am running my code I am getting height and width both zero.

```
class MiglayoutExample extends JFrame {

static JFrame frame;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new JFrame("frame");

    JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
    bluePanel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    bluePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
    redPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

    bluePanel.add(redPanel, "width 100%, height 100%");

    frame.add(bluePanel);

    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    System.out.println("bluePanel.getHeight() = " + bluePanel.getHeight()); //Output 0
    System.out.println("bluePanel.getWidth() = " + bluePanel.getWidth());       //Output 0
    System.out.println("redPanel.getHeight() = " + redPanel.getHeight());       //Output 0
    System.out.println("redPanel.getWidth() = " + redPanel.getWidth());         //Output 0

    frame.show();
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your panel probably don't get their sizes until after the frame has been shown.  Try moving your output statements after `frame.show();`

Comment: *"frame.setSize(600, 600);"* We are usually more concerned with the size of the **content** in the frame, than the size of the frame itself. The decorations or 'chrome' of the panel add more pixels to the size, and that will change according to platform & (sometimes) look-and-feel.

Answer (score -1):

Yours panels have not sizes.
You should set size yours panels

```
redPanel.setSize(600, 600);
bluePanel.setSize(600, 600);
```

Or get frame sizes

```
    System.out.println("frame.getHeight() = " + frame.getHeight()); 
    System.out.println("frame.getWidth() = " + frame.getWidth());
```

Comment: *"You should set size yours panels"* No you should not do that, *especially* when the question states in the title *"..panel **without** set it to fix size"*.